# XNA's how to load XML

Tags: xna

I'm still newbie here...
I tried a tutorial from the internet, about how to load XML in XNA game studio

my code like this :

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
  using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
  using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
  using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
  using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
  using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
  using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
  using System.IO;

 namespace textInput
{

public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    SpriteFont SpriteFont1;
    string credits;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";


    }


    protected override void Initialize()
    {


        base.Initialize();
    }


    protected override void LoadContent()
    {

        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        SpriteFont1 = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("SpriteFont1");

    }


    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {

    }

    public string LoadFromFile()
    {

        using (System.Xml.XmlReader reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create("XMLFile1.xml"))
        {
            reader.MoveToContent();
            reader.ReadToFollowing("credit");
            credits = reader.ReadInnerXml();
        }
        return credits;
    }



    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        base.Update(gameTime);


    }


    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.DrawString(SpriteFont1, credits, new Vector2(20, 40), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }

}
}
```

and when I debug it, ArgumentNullException was unhandled window show on "spriteBatch.DrawString(SpriteFont1, credits, new Vector2(20, 40), Color.White);"

it says, "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: text"

anyone know how to clear this problem???

Comment: sorry to ask again. I tried call LoadFromFile(); in LoadContent().
but when I debug it, the FileNotFoundException wa unhandled window showed. and it says 

"Could not find file 'C:\Documents and Settings\aolas\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\textInput\textInput\textInput\bin\x86\Debug\XMLFile1.xml'."

Comment: That is because the .xml file is not present at the specified location. Place the XMLFile1.xml file near the program's executable (more exactly, here: \textInput\bin\x86\Debug\ ). If you have the .xml file added to your project, be sure to change its properties to "Copy Always" on output directory!

Answer (score 0):

It seems LoadFromFile() does not get called anywhere in your code. Try calling LoadFromFile(); within the LoadContent() method. Provided the XML file is not empty, it should work.
The error is caused because the "credits" string is null (no value assigned to it) at draw time.

Comment: One more thing: you might want to change LoadFromFile()'s return type to "void". It seems you're changing the value of a global variable (credits) within the method and also returning the same variable's value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the XElement etc methods, couse they will give you a lot better controlling over the xml data. You can read the whole xml file into one parent xelement like:

`XElement input = XElement.Load("path-to-xml");`

when your xml looks like:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
`<master-elem>`
 `<some-elem some-attr="x">`
  `y`
 `</some-elem>`
`</master-elem>`

your whole xml file will then be the input element.
your can get the master element with 
`input.Element("master-elem")`
 which returns a XElement which containts all elements in the master-elem. Of course you could call it in a chain and get any value of a element or an attribute of an element. like: 

`input.Element("master-elem").Element("some-elem").Attribute("some-attr").Value`

if you have a larger amount of data, I suggest to have a look at linq which is like sql for objects.

Comment: ( in the other direction you can create XElements and XAttributes into one XElement and then just use its static save method so save it to one xml.